# msbuild: when in the build project is Microsoft.VisualBasic.Targets 'imported' by msbuild?

Tags: msbuild

Here's my situation:  I'm trying to understand how msbuild works by looking at the build files located in the .NET framework install path:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5>dir /s/b microsoft*
Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5.xml
Microsoft.Build.xsd
Microsoft.Common.targets
Microsoft.Common.Tasks
Microsoft.CSharp.targets
Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets
Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets
Microsoft.WinFx.targets
MSBuild\Microsoft.Build.Commontypes.xsd
MSBuild\Microsoft.Build.Core.xsd
```

I'm assuming that msbuild starts with Microsoft.Common.Targets, and then at some point in the future msbuild 'looks' at my vb project file extension (.vbproj) and loads 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets'.

two questions:

1) Is my interpetation correct?

2) can you explain to me, where is the code that determines that this is a .vbproj file, and loads 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets' accordingly?  Is the code locked away in an assembly somewhere, or is it visible in the build files listed above?

Answer (score 1):

It "starts" with your .vbproj file.  Take a look at that file, it will <Import> the Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets, which in turn will <Import> Microsoft.Common.targets.

Answer (score 0):

In 4.0, which is currently available in Beta, there is a /preprocess switch which will make this all clear.